# DynamoDB SDK for .NET Nullable Dates

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm just starting to use the DynamoDB SDK and I was wondering if it handles Nullable dates for a DynamoDBProperty attribute?  It isn't listed in this [document here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) so I'm assuming the answer is no.  If the answer is in fact no, has anyone written a dynamodb type converter to handle nullable date values that they can share?  I found [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ArbitraryDataMappingHLAPI.html) but wasn't sure if I needed it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the converter that I wrote.  If someone else has a better solution let me know.  Hope it helps if you have the same problem.

```
public class DynamoNullableDateConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        DynamoDBEntry entry = new Primitive { Value = null };

        //Format - 2015-03-12T20:24:07.647Z
        if (value != null)
            entry = new Primitive { Value = ((DateTime)value).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffZ") };

        return entry;
    }

    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        Primitive primitive = entry as Primitive;

        if (primitive != null)
        {
            var dtString = primitive.Value.ToString();
            var value = DateTime.Parse(dtString, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
            return value;
        }
        else 
            return (DateTime?)null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've a similar problem. I need to implement a converter not just for a complex type `T`, but for an `IList<T>`. Do I need to create a converter for the type `T` and another one for the `IList<T>`? How can I do that and use those converters with the DynamoDB Attributes?